# How do I move my footer over to the right some?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

So I have a div at the bottom of my page which is good, the problem is that it is overlapping my sidebar on the left, so how do I scoot it over? I trued to do float:right, but it does not seem to do anything, I'm assuming because it's in a fixed position. I also tried to change the width, but that just cuts it from the right side. So how can I get it where I need it, which is just taking up the remaining part of the page where the side bar is not?

I'm shooting for this look: [image: Example]

```
.footer {position:fixed; bottom:0; float:right; background-color:lightgray; font-size:90%}
```

Comment: I think you need to add the actual html and css in order to get some help. How the elements are nested will play a role in the layout.

Comment: Nothing is nested.

Comment: create a jsfiddle with your code in.

Comment: The answer is, it depends. In this case it depends on the width of the sidebar (whether it's a fixed width in pixels or percents etc). So show your code. Without it, any answer will just be guesswork, as you've seen.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [FLEXBOX](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for that

I made a little fiddle using flexbox since you didn't provide your layout

[JSFIDDLE](https://fiddle.jshell.net/hzbduarj/)

Answer (score 0):

The fixed property for the footer is not required.

Also, specifying the footer element as block will 
ensure proper behaviour when applying style to it.

.footer { position: relative;  display: block; background-color: #f2f2f2; float: right; font-size: 90%; width: auto; overflow: hidden; }

The width was set to auto because I don't the exact size of your sidebar. To set it to a number, you need to perform some calculation. For example:

If the sidebar width is 30%, and also has a border, then the total width is: 30.2%;

That is, 1px left plus 1px right borders.

Although, the size depends on the border width.

Then the footer width should be set to 68.8% or 68.75% if it has no border.

Comment: When I do that, the footer jumps to the top of the page just under the heading at the top, any idea why that is?

Comment: Most times, this occurs as a result of less contents on the page.

Add this element before the footer

`<div class="clear_footer"></div>`

Add the style:

`.clear_footer {
    clear: both;
    float: none;
}`

Hopefully, this should fix it.

Comment: It still moves up and still overlaps the sidebar. Is there something wrong with the sidebar CSS? .sideBar {color:white; background-color:gray; float:left; width:12%; position:absolute; top:0; bottom: 0;}

Comment: Try changing the position property in the sidebar from absolute to relative. `position: relative`